# Picture in Picture Surfaceview camera display

Tags: java, android, surfaceview, android-picture-in-picture

I have a surfaceview which shows the camera preview display I want another view over this view which shows the zoomed part of this display in a small frame on top left corner like picture in picture view

Something like this is it feasible to have such kind of view in android.

[image]